# Drag & Drop on "not-allowed Zone" Notification

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

We have the following issue:

We have a application which contains items.

These Items should be drag & droppable on the desktop.

Once we enter drag, the item (in the app) hides.

Now if we drop it anywhere, a shortcut will be created and the item should become visible again, in the app.

Problem:
When the user drops it onto a non-dropable area, the OS doesn't give any notification (as far as we know), so we can't make the hidden item (in the app) visible again.

Hope someone here can help us, or has some good suggestions or workaround. As this is quite a hard issue to solve.

Comment: which language c or c# or wpf or winforms....

Comment: Isn't this what the return value of DoDragDrop() is for?

Comment: I think we have found the answer:
(for anyone searching too)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/dodragdrop-and-mouseup

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer clocked at 50/100ms and check the mouse button state. If it's released and no event has rised yet, the user dropped to an invalid place.

Comment: Mh, yes we thought about something like this already: Just monitor if the "Mouse Left Bt. Release Event" occurs after drag is initiated. But this unfortunately requires a hook to the system, as we can't monitor events outside of the app.

Comment: @auser There is no need for hooks, you can try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input ! However the function doesn't seem reliable as stated in your links description. 
"Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application. The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon."